# Finding the sum of a progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question:** In the A.P. $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...$, every third term is multiplied by $3$, so that the new progression becomes $1, 2, 9, 4, 5, 18, 7, 8, 27, ...$ Find the sum of the first $60$ terms of the new progression.

I don't even know where to start with. I tried to find common difference or common ratio but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You start with $1+2+3+\ldots+60$ then add $\,2 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 6 + \ldots + 2 \cdot 60 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot (1 + 2 + \ldots)\,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the sum $S_n$ of an arithmetic progression with first term $a_1$ and difference equal to $d$ is given by $$S_n=\frac n2[2a+(n-1)d]$$

In our particular case we have the arithmetic progression of the natural numbers $a_n=n$ but with the extra caveat of multiplying every third term, that is, every $a_{3n}$ by $3$.

So, we have the sum $$S=1+2+9+4+5+18+\dots=\\1+2+3+4+5+6+\dots+60+2*(3+6+9+\dots+60)=\\S_n+2\sum_{i=1}^na_{3n}$$

That is, we have the sum of two arithmetic progressions, our initial $a_n$ and two times (the "remaining" terms after taking into account $S_n$) the sum of $b_n=a_{3n}$.

But $a_{3n}$ has as its first term $a_1=3$ and difference $d=3$.

We need to properly count our terms though. For $a_n$ we have the sum of $60$ terms but for $b_n$ we have $\frac{60}{3}=20$ terms.

Thus, we have  $$S=\frac{60}{2}[2*1+(60-1)*1]+2\frac{20}{2}[2*3+(20-1)*3]=3090$$

Answer (score 3):

See, you have the new series as
$$1+2+3×3+4+5+3×6+....+58+59+3×60$$
$$= (1+2+3+4+......+60)+(2×3+2×6+2×9.....+2×60)$$
$$= \frac{60×(60+1)}{2} +2×3(1+2+3+...+20)$$
$$=30×61+2×3×\frac{20×21}{2}$$
$=3090$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

I'll make it very simple.

Take the sum of the A.P. 1,2,3,4...60

Since every third number is wrong, subtract from this sum, the sum of the A.P. 3,6,9,12...60.

Now we are left with the sum of the series 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11...59. We need to add to this the sum of 9,18,27,36..180 i.e. the sum of the remaining numbers. This can be written as 3(3)+3(6)+3(9)+3(12)+...3(60) which in turn can be written as 3(3+6+9+12+...60). Note that this value is the same as thrice the sum of the A.P. found in the paragraph above. So plug in that value and add it. The final value is the answer.

In short you have done this: (sum of 1,2,3,4...60) + 2(sum of 3,6,9,12...60)

You can find the sums of the A.P.s using the general formula. I'm sure you know it already.